# Get MethodInfo of method - This operation is only valid on generic types

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following two Entity Framework's Include methods:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> Include<TEntity, TProperty>(
    [NotNullAttribute] this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
    [NotNullAttribute] Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) 
    where TEntity : class;

public static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity>(
    [NotNullAttribute] this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
    [NotNullAttribute][NotParameterized] string navigationPropertyPath) 
    where TEntity : class;
```

I need to get the MethodInfo for both methods. For the first one I used:

```
  MethodInfo include1 = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
    .GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Include" && x.GetParameters()
    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));
```

This works but when I try to get the second one using the following:

```
  MethodInfo include2 = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
    .GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Include" && x.GetParameters()
    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(String) }));
```

I get the error:

> This operation is only valid on generic types

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `string navigationPropertyPath` generic?

Comment: No, it is just a String ... I added the method signature on top.

Comment: How can `ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` return `typeof(String)` ?

Comment: You probably meant `QueryableExtensions` instead of `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`

Comment: Yes, I understand that it doesn't ... But not sure how to differentiate the 2

Comment: Let me rephrase that question then, you're calling `GetParameters()` on the MethodInfo of `Include(IQueryable<TEntity>, string)`, returning a collection of `{ IQueryable<TEntity>, string }`, and calling `ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on the elements of that. In the case of the string, the latter will fail. It is unclear to me what you're trying to do and why you think this code will do that.

Comment: `string` is not a generic type, so you can't use `y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition` when `y` is the `string navigationPropertyPath` parameter.

Comment: @CodeCaster Shouldn't I compare one GenericParameter type to typeof(IQueryable<>) and the other to String but not generic? I mean, there could be a method with typeof(IQueryable<>), int ... Can you provide the code for your example?

Comment: I cannot provide anything, because your question is unclear. Explain what exactly you want this code to do, and why you think it should do that.

Comment: @haim770 ... Include method is not in QueryableExtensions

Comment: @CodeCaster On the begining of my question I added 2 Include methods. I need to get the MethodInfo of both so I can use them later one with a value. For example, for include1 I would use: (IQueryable<T>)include1.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(String)).Invoke(null, new Object[] { source, navigationSourcePath });

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, lets break this apart. First you want to get all overloads of the method:

```
var overloads = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(method => method.Name == "Include");
```

Then you want to match the parameter types against a particular sequence so you can select the appropriate overload. The problem with your code is that you're assuming all parameters are generic types, when this isn't the case. You can use a ternary clause to distinguish between generic and non-generic parameter types:

```
var include2 =  overloads.Where(method => method
    .GetParameters()
    .Select(param => param.ParameterType.IsGenericType ? param.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : param.ParameterType)
    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(string) }));
```

This produces the second overload, as expected, and doesn't complain about you trying to invoke `GetGenericTypeDefinition` on `typeof(string)` from the second parameter.

Comment: First, I think you meant IsGenericParameter and not IsGenericType. Second, you are not returning MethodInfos but Types. So include2 is a list of Types. And finally I get no items in the end. Any idea why?

Comment: @MiguelMoura No, I mean `IsGenericType`, not `IsGenericParameter`. I tested this myself and it works, see: https://gist.github.com/masaeedu/7150ee92becdad4e514dfa160da460ad. Second, I'm returning an `IEnumerable<MethodInfo>` in both snippets, not `IEnumerable<Type>`. I'd encourage you to paste the code as is into your IDE.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Maybe you're getting confused by the indentation, but the second snippet is literally just your code with the `Select` clause modified to have a ternary expression in it.

Comment: What version of C# are you using? I am using .NET core. Copying your code exactly I get the error: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsGenericType' and no extension method 'IsGenericType' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MiguelMoura I'm using the full framework. Reflection has changed in .NET Core BCL (e.g. you have to `GetTypeInfo`), so you need to mention that kind of thing in your tags if you're using Core. Anyway, there's probably an equivalent for `IsGenericType` in Core, I'll have to google it.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Try `param => param.ParameterType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType ? param.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : param.ParameterType`.

Comment: It works with param.ParameterType.IsConstructedGenericType ... Not sure if it is the equivalent

Comment: @MiguelMoura Thank you, checking if the controller type is generic is important when applying custom attributes